# Invalid JDBC escape syntax at line position 27 '=' character expected

Tags: sql-server, mybatis

Hello i am using java spring mvc framework with mybatis.
I am trying to declare a table-valued parameter (TVP) in mybatis.

```
<select id="Publish">

    DECLARE @tblVar AS type_Publish_idChild;</select>
```

type_Publish_idChild is my user-defined table type

I am getting this error

```
DECLARE @tblVar AS type_Publish_idChild;\n### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid JDBC escape syntax at line position 27 '=' character expected.\n; SQL []; Invalid JDBC escape syntax at line position 27 '=' character expected.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid JDBC escape syntax at line position 27 '=' character expected."
```

Answer (score 0):

A < select > tag is suitable to run a SQL select statement. I didn't know you could use it to declare variables.

The statement must return a number of rows, and this is not the case.